# Problem with exiting a Word doc using Python

Tags: python, excel, ms-word, ms-office

This is my first time using this so be kind :) basically my question is I am making a program that opens many Microsoft Word 2007 docs and reads from a certain table in that document and writes that info to an excel file there is well in excess of 1000 word docs. I have all of this working but the only problem when I run my code it does not close MSword after opening each doc I have to manually do this at the end of the program run by opening word and selecting exit word option from the Home menu. Another problem is also if a run this program consecutively on the second run everything goes to hell it prints the same thing repeatedly no matter which doc is selected I think this may have to do with how MSword is deciding which doc is active e.g. is it still opening the last active document that was not closed from the last run. Anyways here is my code for the opening and closing part I wont bore you guys with the rest::

```
MSWord = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
MSWord.Visible = 0
# Open a specific file
#myWordDoc = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
MSWord.Documents.Open("C:\\Documents and Settings\\fdosier" + chosen_doc)
#Get the textual content
docText = MSWord.Documents[0].Content
charText = MSWord.Documents[0].Characters
# Get a list of tables
ListTables = MSWord.Documents[0].Tables

------Main Code---------

MSWord.Documents.Close
MSWord.Documents.Quit
del MSWord
```

Comment: Does your real code have a missing `"`.  ?

Comment: Thanks All I found a solution to this which is just to do as below by setting ths SaveChanges option to -2 (prompt for save even though the mdsn website says this is optional.                                                                 s               MSWord.Documents.Close(SaveChanges = -2)
                MSWord.Quit

Comment: It seems since I am a new user i have to wait 8 hours before answering my own question i will do it later on though thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, Python is not VBA, so this:

```
MSWord.Documents.Close
```

is equivalent to:

```
getattr(MSWord.Documents, "Close")
```

i.e. you just get some method object and do nothing with it. You need to *call* the method with the **call operator** (the parentheses :) :

```
MSWord.Documents.Close()
```

Accordingly for `.Quit`.

Comment: This is correct the correct answer I would vote it up but cant yet lol thanks though

Answer (score 1):

Before your MSWord.Quit  did you try using:

```
MSWord.ActiveWindow.Close
```

Or even more simpley just doing

```
MSWord.Quit
```

I dont really understand if you are trying to close a document or the application.

Comment: I am not sure myself actually the thing if I run this program once it works fine but after I open Microsft word and select the option EXit Word it closes the hundreds of files that it had previously opened if I do not do this the next time i run the same program it does one of two things generates garabage like I mentioned above or generates and IOError [permission denied in use by another program] or something along those lines. I just want WOrd to release the documents one way or another

Comment: Its really hard to understand what you are doing to get `hundreds` of word documents open... you might want to explain that piece.  When you close your documents does it ask to save?

Comment: I have to parse through a list of word documents and find the some keyword and copy those to an excel table I have not included that code but the number of documents some 2468 which are updated every so often                                                                        It does not ask me to save

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a `MSWord.Quit` at the end (before and/or instead of the the del)

Comment: Thanks it seems you are right del is not needed except to close down all the loose ends i think del just deletes the variable I created